# display a list with the highest points appearing first

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am displaying a list of items where I want the highest point to appear first irrespective of how the data is sorted. At first the snippet that does the logic is working but when inputed with different variables as shown in the table structure, the expected logic output fails. Here is the entity structure

```
books.php
id | name | points | active
1  | huk  | 5      | true
2  | foo  | 2      | true
3  | doo  | 2      | true
4  | jack | 12     | true
```

Here is my controller snippets

```
$restresults = $this->getDoctrine()
                        ->getRepository('xxxBundle:Books')
                        ->findBy(
                            ['active' => true],
                            ['points' => 'DESC']
                        );
```

the above snippets result is unpredictable from my coding intention, as it returns this result in sorting in respect to book points 5, 2, 2, 12 instead of 12, 5 , 2 , 2.

Please what could be wrong with my algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at sorting result it looks like the string type is sorted instead of int.

To fix that change the type of column points to int both in doctrine and db for example with `@Column(type="integer") */` depending on your style of mapping.

The other way is to make DQL. If you can't do it then you need to make your own DQL

and write orderby there.

Ex.

```
$books = $em->getRepository('xxxBundle:Books')
    ->createQueryBuilder('q')
    ->addSelect('ABS(q.points) AS HIDDEN pointsOrder') // other way CAST(q.points AS UNSIGNED)
    ->orderBy('pointsOrder', 'DESC)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```